# PHP JSON parsing (number attributes?)

Tags: php, json, object

Hi i have a JSON string like this:

```
{
"vidID": "CevxZvSJLk8",
"vidTitle": "Katy Perry - Roar (Official)",
"vidInfo": {
    "0": {
        "rSize": "67.79 MB",
        "quality": "720",
        "directurl": "https://r2---sn-5uh5o-f5f6.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ipbits=0&mm=31&mn=sn-5uh5o-f5f6&itag=22&mt=1492837642&dur=269.165&id=o-AB1T_kZWIIiA_ihhSlAK4RXegp3Z9A18zn39hF0Aa51G&initcwndbps=197500&pl=21&source=youtube&mv=m&ip=137.74.1.176&mime=video%2Fmp4&ms=au&ratebypass=yes&requiressl=yes&sparams=dur%2Cei%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&key=yt6&lmt=1478841669593636&upn=Wp652d9rFKo&ei=OuX6WLqMDJaLNK-MmLAE&expire=1492859290&signature=A8B328D48101C553D0659D2D9D1F1B2F249D2035.792897E2CF6BFEFC97C81A90EA9CBF9B76FD0283&type=video%252Fmp4%253B%2Bcodecs%253D%2522avc1.64001F%252C%2Bmp4a.40.2%2522&quality=hd720&title=Katy%2BPerry%2B-%2BRoar%2B%2528Official%2529",
        "dloadUrl": "//downloadmp.org/@download/22-58fae53acfc14-mp4-71087585/videos/CevxZvSJLk8/Katy%2BPerry%2B-%2BRoar%2B%2528Official%2529.mp4",
        "ftype": "mp4",
        "framerate": "",
        "bitrate": "",
        "codec": "",
        "itag": "22",
        "vidid": "CevxZvSJLk8"
    }}}
```

And i am trying to get value of direct url.
So here is my PHP code:

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->vidInfo[0]->directurl;
```

Also tried this

```
echo $obj->vidInfo->0->directurl;
```

but i can't get the value of attribute direct url.

Comment: `$obj = json_decode($json,true);
    echo $obj[0]['vidInfo'][0]['directurl']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, `"0"` isn't a number, so you cant use the normal array access. Instead, you have to access it like an name. But as `0` isn't a valid identifier, you have to use the `{}`-syntax.

```
echo $obj->vidInfo->{"0"}->directurl;
```

The other way to get around this problem would be to pass `true` as second param to `json_decode`. Doing this would return you an assoc array and not the object format.

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
echo $data['vidInfo'][0]['directurl'];
```

Comment: Thanks this is what i was looking for also i do not know who gived that downgrade and why. I am new to stackoverflow so i can not give an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

To get the object form try this:

```
var_dump(get_object_vars($obj));
```

I like to convert json to an array.

```
$array = json_decode($json,true);
echo $array ['vidInfo'][0]['directurl']
```

Here the rest of the data:

```
vidID => string:  $array['vidID'] => CevxZvSJLk8
vidTitle => string:  $array['vidTitle'] => Katy Perry - Roar (Official)
rSize => string:  $array['vidInfo'][0]['rSize'] => 67.79 MB
quality => string:  $array['vidInfo'][0]['quality'] => 720
directurl => string:  $array['vidInfo'][0]['directurl'] => https://r2---sn-5uh5o-f5f6.googlevideo.com/vide truncated 687 char
dloadUrl => string:  $array['vidInfo'][0]['dloadUrl'] => //downloadmp.org/@download/22-58fae53acfc14-mp4 truncated 60 char
ftype => string:  $array['vidInfo'][0]['ftype'] => mp4
framerate => string:  $array['vidInfo'][0]['framerate'] => 
bitrate => string:  $array['vidInfo'][0]['bitrate'] => 
codec => string:  $array['vidInfo'][0]['codec'] => 
itag => string:  $array['vidInfo'][0]['itag'] => 22
vidid => string:  $array['vidInfo'][0]['vidid'] => CevxZvSJLk8
```